# how to scroll collectionview cell horizontally and vertically..i am using 9 cell collectionview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am totally new for collection view, please help me with scrolling cell vertically and horizontally in collection view :

```
viewcontroller.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate>
{

UICollectionView *collectionView;

}
@end



viewcontroller.m

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];

    collectionView=[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame 
collectionViewLayout:layout];

    [collectionView setDataSource:self];

    [collectionView setDelegate:self];

    [collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] 

forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];

    [collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    [self.view addSubview:collectionView];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return 9;

}
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];


    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];

    return cell;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    return CGSizeMake(100, 100);

}
@end
```

Comment: Please elaborate. Do you want to scroll programmatically? Do you want to make it scrollable for users?

Comment: yes i want to make it collectionview scrollable programatically???

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late here, but just in case anybody else looks this up, you can easily set your collection view scroll direction by using UICollectionViewFlowLayout.

1. Create an instance of UICollectionViewFlowLayout
2. Set the scrollDirection to UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal
3. Rejoice.

   -(instancetype) init
   {
       UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];
       layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(106, 106);
       layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1;
       layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1;
       layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
       self= [super initWithCollectionViewLayout:layout];
       return self;
   }

Answer (score 0):

you can scroll the collectionview programmaticaly with the  follwing methods of UICollectionView class:

```
[collectionView scrollsToTop];
[collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:<#(NSIndexPath *)#> atScrollPosition:<#(UICollectionViewScrollPosition)#> animated:<#(BOOL)#>];
[collectionView scrollRectToVisible:<#(CGRect)#> animated:<#(BOOL)#>];
```

Comment: there where you want to scroll to a specific position inside the view controller which includes the scrollview